# Having trouble creating vectors of System::String^

Tags: .net, vector, c++-cli, clr

So I have a regex expression to parse certain parts of a file name. I'm trying to store each part in its own vector until I use it later, but it won't let me. One error I get when I try making a vector of System::String^ is that `error C3698: 'System::String ^' : cannot use this type as argument of 'new'` Then, when I try just making a vector of std::string, it can't implicitly convert to type System::String^, and casting won't work either.

```
void parseData()
{
    System::String^ pattern = "(\\D+)(\\d+)(\\w{1})(\\d+)\\.(\\D{3})";
    std::vector < System::String^ > x, y, filename, separator;

    Regex re( pattern );

    for ( int i = 0; i < openFileDialog1->FileNames->Length; i++ )
    {
        Match^ m = re.Match( openFileDialog1->FileNames[i] );
        filename.push_back( m->Groups[0]->Value );/*
        x.push_back( m->Groups[1]->Value );
        separator.push_back( m->Groups[2]->Value );
        y.push_back( m->Groups[3]->Value );*/
    }                       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the STL/CLR library if you really prefer using STL collections.  It isn't exactly popular, [this web page](http://www.voidnish.com/Articles/ShowArticle.aspx?code=StlClrBclComparison) shows you why.

Use `List<String^>`

Answer (score 1):

std::vector uses new to allocate it's objects, but you can't allocate System::String^ with new, since it's a managed type.

Comment: Consider using std::string instead, or a managed collection type like List<String^>.

Comment: @iconiK: I already said that.. 
@TreDubZedd: I already said i tried std:string as well. I'll try List< System::String^ > tomorrow though.

Comment: @Justen, where did you say that std::vector uses new to allocate it's objects and it can't do that for managed ones?

Comment: But that's not quite the point. You didn't provide an answer, but told me what the error I already posted was (though in slightly more detail). All in all, no new solutions.

Comment: There's no solution if you are intent on using STL collections of managed types.  There are workarounds.

Comment: @above - I wasn't intent on using them, just unaware of alternatives. Went with List< String^ > and it worked perfectly.